# Silveright Prism: How to wait for two events

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism-4

I am using Prism for my application and 
I got 3 modules called A, B, C.

A fires an event x, B fires an event y.

C will be listened these two events x and y.

In case of event x => event handler called XEventHandler => Which will generate object A.

In case of event y => event handler called YEventHandler

In YEventHandler, Object A will be used. So I need some way to handle this so that:

1. If Object A is created => YEventHanlder will be executed if module C catch y Event
2. If Object A is not created yet (x event haven't been fired yet or the process of creating object A hasn't finished yet) => YEventHanlder need to wait until object A is ready and continue.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks for such a cool community.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a quite common task. Eventhandler Y has to wait for a [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx), e.g. [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx). This ResetEvent is set when object A is created.

```
private AutoResetEvent objectACreated = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private A a = null;

void HandlerY(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(objectACreated.WaitOne())
    {
        a.DoSomething();
    }
}

void HandlerX(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    a = new A();
    objectACreated.Set();
}
```